# Using C++11 lambda functions in ARC ObjectiveC++ - how to do it properly?

Tags: objective-c, lambda, c++11, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I have an ObjectiveC++ project. In the ObjectiveC context I am using ARC and iPhoneSDK 6. In C++ I am using a C++11 compiler.

Lambda functions in C++11 are capturing variables with references. This concept is not really supported by ObjectiveC and by "try and error" I came up with the following solution. Are there any pitfalls I am not aware of?

Is there a better solution to this problem?

```
typedef std::function<void ()> MyLambdaType;

...
// m_myView will not go away. ARC managed.
UIView * __strong m_myView;

...
// In Objective C context I create a lambda function that calls my Objective C object
UIView &myViewReference = *m_myView;
MyLambdaType myLambda = [&myViewReference]() {
    UIView *myViewBlockScope = &myViewReference;
    // Do something with `myViewBlockScope`
}

..
// In C++11 context I call this lambda function
myLambda();
```

Comment: AFAIK blocks are ObjectiveC only, or? How do I pass a block to C++ ?

Comment: Does `MyLambdaType myLambda = [m_myView]() { // Do something with m_myView }` not work?

Comment: @newacct AFAIK a copy is created in that case. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: @LarsSchneider: yes, a copy of `m_myView`, a pointer to your object. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @newacct I am insanely stupid. You're right. Do you want to create an "answer" so I can give give you the answer points?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The straightforward thing to do would be to let the lambda capture the object pointer variable `m_myView` (I am assuming from your snippet that this is a local variable), and use it normally inside the lambda:

```
MyLambdaType myLambda = [m_myView]() {
    // Do something with `m_myView`
}
```

The only concern would be the memory management of `m_myView`. To be generally correct, the lambda needs to retain `m_myView` when it is created, and release it when it is destroyed (just like blocks do; because the lambda could be used in a scope where `m_myView` does not exist).

Reading through the ARC docs, I don't see this situation mentioned specifically, but I believe that it should handle it properly, because (1) captured variables of a C++11 lambda are stored as fields of an anonymous class, which are initialized to the captured value when the lambda is constructed, and (2) ARC properly handles the retaining and releasing of Objective-C object fields of C++ classes on construction and destruction. Unless it says something specifically about lambdas to the contrary, or there's a compiler bug, I see no reason why it should not work.

Comment: This definitely works. The tricky thing is that in C++11 lambda terminology, `m_myView` is being captured "by value" here. If you capture it "by reference" (like this: `[&m_myView](){...}`) the object `m_myView` is *NOT* retained by ARC. If you think about it, this makes perfect sense (i.e. when you tell C++ to capture `m_myView` by reference, C++ is capturing a reference *to the pointer*, not a reference to the object) but the terminology can be a bit confusing.

Comment: @ipmcc: Yes. This is true for capturing by reference in C++11 lambdas in general. If you capture by reference in C++11 lambda, then you cannot use that lambda outside the scope of those captured variables.

Comment: It seems the memory used by m_myView is not released by ARC. I am getting a lot of callbacks every few milliseconds in my code and my memory is steadily jumping. Its the same for Objective-C objects created inside the lambda function. They are leaking too.

Comment: @AshishAwaghad You need to make sure that you `m_myView` doesn't hold a strong reference to the lambda. The fact that you have memory leak is probably because you get into a retain circle there.

Comment: I, too, was leaking an (`NSData`) object which was captured by a lambda. The leak was fixed by wrapping the statements within the lambda within an `@autoreleasepool` block.